# How can I add Maven build dependencies on Android with React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, maven

could you please tell me how can I add Maven build dependencies on Android with React Native?
I am trying to add the dependency, in build.gradle:

implementation 'com.zxy.android:tiny:1.1.0'

But when trying to run the application, it shows the following error message:
[image: error message]

What am I missing to implement?

Comment: can you share build.gradle file ?

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1744774)

Comment: Is the `<groupID>` really `com.zxy.android`? This looks more like a code sample placeholder. If it is real where did you find it, where is it supposed to come from?